# Structure position html

Tags: html, gwtbootstrap3

my english is so bad. Bear with me.

I cant move de position of a button submit. All styles have no effect.

This is the code (html, bootstrap 3):

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12"> 
            <!-- LOGO -->
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <img src="../web/assets/img/logo-biblioteca.png" alt="Biblioteca Virtual">
            </div>

            <!-- BUSCADOR -->
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="well" >
                    <form class="form-group" action="">
                        <div class="col-sm-1" style="margin-top: 0.5%">
                            <label for="titulo"><b> Título </b></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-11">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese un titulo" name="titulo" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-1" style="margin-top: 2.5%">
                            <label for="autor"><b> Autor </b></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-11" style="margin-top: 2%">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese un autor" name="autor" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="text-right row">
                            <button class="btn btn-info btn-md" type="submit">Buscar</button>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

I cant move the button Buscar.

Comment: Thanks for the language warning, however (`I cant move de position of a button submit. All styles have no effect`)  we need to know what you are trying to get as the end result.  Where are you trying to move the button?

Comment: Can you put a screenshot of your expected output please?

Answer (score 0):

Please tell us more information, but you can also attempt to try this when using inline styling: !important;

Example..

```
<div id="placement" class="text-left"> <!-- text-center, text-right works too. -->
<button here>button</button>
</div>
```

This should work with Bootstrap, if you have it installed properly.
You could also attempt to put a float:left/right on the button itself and see what happens.

Comment: i cant solve the problem. I splain in spanish.

El problema era que tenia anidados muchos div, con lo cual habia problemas con el display (quedaban desordenados visualmente sin poder modificar su posición). La soulción fué sacar divs que estaban de más y agregas las clases que contenian a los div hijos.